# Google Apps Script runtime Chrome V8 causes error in and Utilities.parseCsv(csv, delimiter) when delimiter is ' ' (space)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In Google App script, I need to split a string using space as delimiter. I have used Utilities.parseCsv. Worked fine.

Then, I switched my script code to the new V8 runtime and encountered a bug with the parse.CSV function. This simple code below fails in V8, works fine in the legacy runtime. Error is "Exception: Cannot convert '' to char.".

I like to use the V8 runtime for the reasons so need to get this working. Does anybody have a workaround for that, please?

Thank you very much!

```js
function test(){
var csvString = "Prefix Middle Suffix";
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString, ' ');
Logger.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You want to use `Utilities.parseCsv(csv, delimiter)` under V8.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

I think that this might be one of bugs for V8. Although I think that this might be resolved in the future update. As the current workaround, from the error message of `Exception: Cannot convert '' to char.`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString, ' ');
```

#### To:

```
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString, ' '.charCodeAt(0));
```

or

```
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString, Utilities.newBlob(' ').getBytes());
```

#### Result:

```
[["Prefix","Middle","Suffix"]]
```

#### Note:

- In above modified script, it can be used with and without enabling V8.

#### References:

- [parseCsv(csv, delimiter)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String,Char))
- [charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)
- [newBlob(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(String))
- [getBytes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getBytes())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike! Your solutions works for me!!