# Import CSV from bucket using appscript

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to import some data from a bucket i have set up using appscript. My plan was to get the attachment from my bucket, save it as a variable, then use the utilities.parseCsv() to parse it, then put in a sheets.

```
import_data_from_bucket() {
var url  = 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/csvloadtest99/test1.csv';
var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(text,',');

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TestSheet");
var Row = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
var Col = sheet.getLastColumn();
sheet.getRange(Row, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
       }
```

It doesn't seem to be able to parse the 'text' variable. Any help in getting this working would be appreciated!

thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the detail of your issue from `It doesn't seem to be able to parse the 'text' variable.`, when you have already confirmed that `text` of `var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();` is the CSV values, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60162085/7108653

Comment: thanks for the reply. to clarify, i get this error message, "Exception: Could not parse text" i tried some of the variations on the link provided, and it produces the same error

Comment: Thank you for replying. In this case, in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample value of `text` of `var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();`?

Comment: ive edited the code and created a public bucket and file..to show the issue im facing.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. When I checked it, unfortunately, it seems that the value retrieved by the URL is not the CSV data. It's the HTML of `<title>Sign in - Google Accounts</title>`. Can you confirm about this by putting `console.log(text)` to below `var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(,,,)`?

Comment: I believe the issue is with the google url. I have tried the same code using an AWS public S3 bucket URL and the code works.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.